# Is it possible to embed Gazebo simulator in your own GUI?

Tags: ros, gazebo, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am working on a graphical user interface for ROS. I wanted to ask if it is possible to embed a simulator in your own gui i.e. its window opens inside your window?

Any constructive response would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274592/is-it-possible-to-embed-gazebo-simulator-in-your-own-gui?/) by [YusraAzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/30010/yusraazhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-10-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it is possible to embed Gazebo's client window into another Qt application, whether that uses ROS or not. Just like the RViz example mentioned on another answer, Gazebo can also be used as a library.

I just created a simple example program which does that:

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-requests/2804/add-example-embedding-gzclient-into-a/diff

Here's what it looks like:

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.ros.org/users/4654/chapulina/) with karma: 366 on 2017-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [YusraAzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/30010/yusraazhar/) on 2017-11-21**:
Have you ever tried doing this in Python?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.ros.org/users/4654/chapulina/) on 2017-11-21**:
I haven't, Gazebo's API is all in C++